# How are equation of that form $a^x\equiv b \mod n$ often named?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

How are equation of that form $a^x\equiv b \mod n$ usually named? I am trying to solve $7^x\equiv 6 \mod 17$ but I am having troubles doing so for I don't know enough properties of this kind of equations and can't find proper explanation because of etymological issues. I would appreciate any reference or help either with trying to solve it or with referring my lacking information in that matter. Note: I am not native and my English is poor.

Comment: "Discrete logarithm" comes to mind.

Comment: It is generally assumed that finding such an $x$ is difficult - various cryptographic procedures rely on the fact.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it is called "discrete logarithm" or "discrete logarithm problem".

This is a very hard problem to solve in general, it is used in cryptography.
This means, there is probably no 'nice' way to solve it, so i suggest to try every number from 1 to 16 for $x$

Comment: I am not a brilliant student of "Number Theory", so would you say I am expected to check? 
I already found that 3 is a primitive root modulo 17.